# Find all records in mysql group

Tags: mysql, group-by

I know I can find duplicate records by doing

```
Select FieldA
     , FieldB
     , FieldC Count(*) 
  from Table 
 group 
    by FieldA
     , FieldB 
 having count(*)>1
```

and get a list of single records matching the query and a count of how many records match that query. What  I want to do is display all of the records not just the count(*).

So instead of just finding

```
'Red','Apple','NY','2'
'Blue','Berry','CA','3'
```

I find

```
'Red','Apple','NY','2'
'Red','Apple','NM','2'
'Blue','Berry','CA','3'
'Blue','Berry','NY','3'
'Blue','Berry','AZ','3'
```

Comment: Just join what you have back on to your table

Comment: Do group by with one column